# How to stop my iPhone iMessages syncing to my sons iPod as we share my Apple ID

Tags: iphone, messages, apple-id, ipod

My son recently updated his iPod and i gave him access to my Apple ID so he can download games via wifi and access shared music - problem is my iMessages are syncing...what can i do to stop that from happening?

Comment: Don't share Apple IDs, use [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060) instead

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you check iMessages> Preferences > Accounts

If there are any Apple ID's other than yours, be sure to get rid of them.